# Set flyway script locations with FlywayConfigurationCustomizer

Tags: quarkus, flyway

I added a bean as described in https://quarkus.io/guides/flyway#customizing-flyway
to customize the location of migrations scripts.

```
@Singleton
public static class MyCustomizer implements FlywayConfigurationCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(FluentConfiguration configuration) {
        configuration.locations("db/migration", "otherlocation/migration");
    }
}
```

It runs the bean but it seems like the config is overridden afterwards?

Is it even possible to change the scripts locations this way? Has anyone done this?

Comment: What do they get overriden by?

Comment: It ends up using the default location path, "db/migration".
I'm not sure it's overriding the settings, but setting the locations in FlywayConfigurationCustomizer doesn't seem to do anything at least.

Comment: Have you tried adding a breakpoint inside `configuration.locations` to see what else is calling it?